# Where to put .mp3 file in visual C# project.?

Tags: c#, mp3, naudio

I am designing a small application in visual C# Winforms. I am using a NAudio and playing an .mp3 file. Below is the code:

```
IWavePlayer waveOutDevice = new WaveOut();
AudioFileReader audioFileReader = new AudioFileReader("ringtone.mp3");

waveOutDevice.Init(audioFileReader);
waveOutDevice.Play();
```

I have saved this `ringtone.mp3` in debug folder. But I think if I use this exe on another system. Then this mp3 will not work. So I want to know where I can save this mp3 file inside the project and the how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1:
You will have to make sure that the mp3 file is always on the same folder as the exe file. Maybe create an installer which will copy both files on the same folder.

Option 2:
Embed the mp3 file inside the exe. Just copy the mp3 inside your Visual Basic solution and set it's **Build Actions** to **Embedded Resource**

Then in your code you will refer to it with this:

```
Stream mp3FileStream = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("YourSolution.ringtone.mp3");
```

This will return a Stream object. You will have to see how to pass that to your IWavePlayer object.

*My guess is something like this `waveOutDevice.Init(mp3FileStream)`, but did not even tested this.*

Comment: where are these options for Build Actions to Embedded Resource

Comment: On the properties panel, after you select the file from your project. Here is a screenshot: https://www.evernote.com/l/AWmFHCnm2t5O_5rCcvB4LJO6hTcosIo6VZU

Comment: OK I have set build actions to embedded resources. Where should I put that line of code which you have mentioned in your answer.?

Comment: You can start putting them in the same place from where you have pasted the code from your question.

Answer (score 0):

Just add it to the project.
Right click on the project => Add => Existing Item...
pick the file from the file picker.
It will be sent to the output folder on compilation.